# Rails: How to render more than one partial from one controller's action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views, renderpartial

I'm creating comments and I use `create.js` file that contains an ajax call to add comments,

Now I'm adding notification into a partial, I want the notification section to refresh at the same time when the comment is added,

I'm trying to do this but it doesn't work, I was wondering if there would be a way around it:

inside `def create` action

```
if @comment.save
  track_activity @comment  
  #refresh_dom_with_partial('div#comments_container', 'comments')
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { @comments = @commentable.user_comments.order(:created_at) }
    format.html #{ redirect_to @commentable }
    render :partial => "layouts/notification"

  end
else
  render :new
end
```

the `render :partial => "layouts/notification"` is kind of breaking the comment Ajax call as well.
Bottom line: I don't know how to refresh more than 1 partial from this action.

Comment: you can create a specific view, in which you render any of other partial views, it is just recursive partial view.

Comment: @majioa is there an example of this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can render the partial inside create.js

`$("#some_div_id").empty().html("<%=escape_javascript(render('layouts/notification'))%>");`

Comment: I just up voted your reply :), correction to my earlier comment! Now it does get appended, but surprisingly it shows up as it's invisible, there the actual thing gets added, but still doesn't show up as in the view :/ !

Comment: @observer. that technique definitely works, I cut and pasted from one of my applications

Comment: this worked! But, Sadly I'm mistaken the way I want the notifications to reload is not this way :/ !